# How to handle all app link in instant app

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

Web is live with www.xyz.com/status/homestatus, www.xyz.com/status/rentstatus and many more.

Currently I have provided support for www.xyz.com/status/homestatus.
But I want to control this only via www.xyz.com/status/*
So that whenever user click on any link, redirected to instant app.

Then Within app I will check for full url and open the respective tab for home status or rent status.

Any suggestion please

Answer (score 1):

Add the following code in your Instant App manifest file.

```
<intent-filter
            android:order="1"
            android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:scheme="https"
                android:host="www.abc.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/status/"
                />
        </intent-filter>
```